# Ionic fails to build or run the application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-build, ionic-cli

I'm trying to build my ionic app, but it fails with below error. The error is same with `ionic run android` command too. The app runs with no error with `ionic serve` command. I have even tried with `ionic cordova build ios` and the error remains same.

Error:

```
npm run ionic:build:before
Pay@0.0.1 ionic:build:before d:\PsResources\DroidWorkspace\Pay\Pay
node ./src/bin/script.js

module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 
'd:\PsResources\DroidWorkspace\Pay\Pay\src\bin\script.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Pay@0.0.1 ionic:build:before: `node ./src/bin/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Pay@0.0.1 ionic:build:before script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Suroor\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-10-30T17_30_14_997Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

    npm run ionic:build:before exited with exit code 1.
Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Ionic Info:

```
Ionic:
   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.2.1 (C:\Users\Suroor\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:
    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
    Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.1, browser 4.1.0, ios 4.3.1
    Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 5 other plugins)

System:

 (D:\Software\~ProgrammingTools\SDK)
   NodeJS            : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 7
```

Solutions Tried:

1. Deleted node_modules and installed again.
2. Removed and installed latest version of cordova and ionic-app-scripts.
3. Downgraded cordova to 4.2.0.
4. All env variables are proper.

**Update:**
Its trying to access `script.js` file from `d:\PsResources\DroidWorkspace\Pay\Pay\src\bin\script.js` which is not even exist.

Comment: Looking at the error, it looks to be related to the Pay module, whatever library that is. I'd look into that module library usage. Make sure that you are installing it and defining it in your modules correctly, if it has module support.

Comment: If there's any error in modules it wont run using serve command, but in my case it runs with no error using serve command

Comment: what library is Pay@0.0.1 ?

Comment: Its not library, its my app name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this (May not be appropriate), I removed

```
"ionic:watch:before": "node ./src/bin/script.js",
"ionic:build:before": "node ./src/bin/script.js"
```

from `package.json` scripts, and now it builds successfully. I don't know what is the purpose of above scripts, but it works for now, and generated Apk works fine in the device.